# I am trying to upload data to server and data is in blob

Tags: javascript, ajax, filereader, ashx

I am trying to upload data to server and data is in blob and the problem is when the file is empty it gets upload but it won't if file contain any data in it 
    following is my code

```
function uploadData() 
{
    var param = {
        subjectName: $("#ipName").val(),
        subjectID: $("#DocSubject").val(),
        typeID: $("#DocType").val(),
        year: $("#ipDate").val(),
        data: dataURL.substr(dataURL.indexOf(',') + 1, dataURL.length),
 };
  Handler("Json", param, "UploadData");
}
var dataURL;
var handleFiles = function (event) {

    var input = event.target;

    var reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload=function(){
         dataURL=reader.result;
        var output=document.getElementById('ipSelect');
        output.src=dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}
```

Handler is .ashx file which save my data to sql server.I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Where is `uploadData` called? No `Blob` appears at Question, other than `input.files[0]`, which is a `File` object which inherits from `Blob`. Are you trying to upload `dataURL` at `Handler("Json", param, "UploadData")` within `uploadData()` call?

Comment: uploadData is onclick function as I click on that button it retrives data from a web form .My Web form has one input field with type="file" and I want as I click on that button uploadData function to be called up and than It should take all required data.blob is one of them.

Comment: I want on uploadData() call blob data to be passed not dataURL.

Comment: You should be able to remove pass `input.files[0]` to `uploadData`, as `File` object inherits from `Blob`, though `uploadData` appears to expect `data URI`?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you ,I want to pass blob data to uploadData() ,can you suggest me how can I achieve that ,it will be good help if you can provide me with some example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReader()` `.readAsDataURL()` method returns results asynchronously. You can pass `dataURL` to `uploadData()` call at `load` event of `FileReader`. Note also, that `reader.result`:`dataURL` is a [`data URI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) returned from `.readAsDataURL()`, not a `Blob`

```
function uploadData(dataURL) 
{
    var param = {
        subjectName: $("#ipName").val(),
        subjectID: $("#DocSubject").val(),
        typeID: $("#DocType").val(),
        year: $("#ipDate").val(),
        data: dataURL.substr(dataURL.indexOf(',') + 1, dataURL.length)
 };
  Handler("Json", param, "UploadData");
}
var dataURL;
var handleFiles = function (event) {

    var input = event.target;

    var reader=new FileReader();
    reader.onload=function(){
         dataURL=reader.result;
        var output=document.getElementById('ipSelect');
        output.src=dataURL;
        uploadData(dataURL); // call `uploadData()` with `dataURL` as parameter
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

}
```